# My Bot Framework Composer bot stops answering in Teams after publishing new version to Azure

Tags: azure, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am currently developing a chatbot in Bot Framework Composer for Teams. When I publish a new version from Composer to Azure, my bot suddenly stops answering. However, if I delete the chat with the bot in teams and open it again (using the "Open in Teams" button in Azure Portal), it starts answering again. It works directly when talking to the new version in Web Chat so this is probably related to the connection to Teams. Does anyone know why this happens and know if there is any solution to the problem?

[Before the conversation is deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFM9V.png)

[After the conversion is deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRtgy.png)

Comment: 1.This issue might be related to the bot's endpoint URL not being updated in the Microsoft Bot Framework developer portal.
To verify this, go to Configuration > Bot Messaging in the Microsoft Bot Framework developer portal and check if the endpoint has been set correctly.


2.If the endpoint is set correctly, then the issue might be related to the bot's Microsoft app ID and password not being saved correctly in the bot configuration file you uploaded to the web app.Verify that the bot's Microsoft app ID and password are saved correctly in the bot configuration file.

Comment: According to my knowledge after every deployment you need to restart the chat bot so it will be updated to the recently deployed one.

Comment: 1. The messaging endpoint is correct. It doesn't change as I am uploading a new version to Azure.

2. What do you mean by bot configuration file? The publishing profile? I believe the App ID and password are stored correctly since otherwise I would get a Error when I upload the bot to Azure.

I think these things would affect the web chat channel as well and as I mentioned above the Web Chat channel answer directly without having to "delete" the chat. There must be a way to restart the chat bot in Teams without having to delete the conversation..

Comment: Did you try uploading the correct Teams App Manifest into the Teams desktop client for testing instead of just clicking "Open in Teams"? The App Manifest is how Teams Apps are "installed", and thus is the best way to test Teams apps. It should respond without needing to delete and re-add.

Comment: @AP01 I have not tried that no. So you suggest that I should set up a CI/CD pipeline for the Teams app since we need to "upload" the updated App Manifest to Teams when we update the bot? I was hoping that I could only upload it to Azure bot and everything would work directly.

Comment: You can upload the manifest directly into your local Teams installation by using the "Manage Your Apps" and "Upload an App" menus. It's not an appropriate way to distribute a production Teams app, but it's a great way to test while in development.

Comment: Thanks @AP01! Alright, that is as you say a way to test it during development. It is not that tiring to remove the conversation either during the testing phase but in production, it is not optimal. Do you know if following this CI/CD guideline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-cicd is sufficient for a bot that is intended to be used in Teams or do we need one for the Teams app itself also?

Comment: A production CI/CD pipeline is good for building and hosting your bot. For publishing to Teams, look into [Distribute your Teams app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-publish-overview). on the Teams docs. This step is separate from your bot.